# Get only specific values from External CSV File

Tags: data, csv

I'm struggling to find out the best solution to the following scenario:
I have a big static csv file containing data not related to salesforce. I would like to get a specific value on my csv file and save it on a specific field on the account.
How can I create the connection between my org and my local csv file? I tried to upload the csv file on Documents in my org but it's too big. I think dataloader is not my solution because it needs an external id to update the account but in my csv file I have data not related to salesforce.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you connecting the rows in your CSV to your Salesforce accounts? What data point do they have in common?

Comment: Hi David, thank you for reply. I have a custom field on the account as external id, when this field is equal to a value of the column used as external id in the csv file, I have to get the values of the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Data Loader to **upsert** your accounts, matching them on your External Id column. Make sure to select the Upsert operation, and tell Data Loader you want to match using that field.

Data Loader will provide you with an opportunity to map columns between your CSV file and your Salesforce object. When you do so, you'll map only those fields that you want to update. It doesn't matter if there is a lot of unrelated data in your CSV - simply don't map those fields. Only the fields you map will be updated in Salesforce by Data Loader.

It sounds like you need to map *only* your External Id and a single other field. That's fine. If it increases your comfort level, simply create a copy of your CSV and delete all of the other columns before beginning your load process.

If the value you are working with is *not*, in fact, an External Id and you cannot make it such for some reason, your next step is likely to use a tool like LibreOffice or Microsoft Excel to perform an `INDEX()/MATCH()` or `VLOOKUP()` pass to map from your shared data point to a Salesforce Id or External Id column on the Account. You would then use that value to perform your update or upsert operation.

In that situation, you'll need to take care to handle case correctly - if your non-external-Id is not case-safe, be aware that these Excel functions treat, e.g., `AAa` and `AAA` as equivalent. You can get around this using array functions, but it can be excruciatingly slow. You'll also have to account for any duplicate values appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but I'm sorry I made a mistake, because the field on the account (that I use to filter the csv row) is not an external id.

Comment: Can you *make* it an External Id? Is it unique?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: I've added some notes. If you cannot use an external Id, you'll have to do a much more manual process.

Comment: Thanks again David, but I would like to make it as automatical process writing Apex code if necessary, because it would be a static csv file, so I shouldn't handle it. My problem is just how I should start in order to read the csv, because I can't upload the file on Salesforce (too big).

Comment: Antonio, I might suggest that you open a new question and be very specific about your scenario. Remember that details like whether or not you have an External Id, the size of your file, and how you need to process it have a huge impact on your best solution.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I could have been more specific in my question, thanks for your time.